# How to make login limit in NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I want to build login limit in NodeJs

I want to prevent attempts to login  multiple times with client IP

How should I modify this part?

This is my login function

```
var login = function(id, password, callback) {

    pool.getConnection(function(err, poolConn){
        if (err)
            {
                if(poolConn){
                    poolConn.release();
                }
                callback(err, null);
                return;
            }
        console.log(poolConn.threadId);
        var tablename = 'users';
        var columns = ['id', 'nickname'];

        var exec = poolConn.query("select ?? from ?? where id = ? and password = ?", [columns, tablename, id, password], function(err, rows){
            poolConn.release();

            if (err){
                callback(err, null);
                return;
            }

            if (rows.length > 0){
                console.log(rows);
                callback(null, rows);
            }
            else{
                callback(null, null);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it per user you can have a loginAttemps column in your database

If you want to do it per clientIP you can use a rate limiter like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit)

This package stores the ips in memory but you can set up a way to store ips in a database and hook it up to it